# Nested classes not working in CSS Modules with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader, css-modules

Im using webpack and css-loader and style-loader to enable css modules in my React app. These are the following setup:

Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: __dirname + "/app/index.js",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/build"
    },
    plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

And in my React component I've coded this:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Carousel.css";   

class Carousel extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles["carousel"]}>
                <img
                    className={styles["test"]}
                    src="https://i2.wp.com/beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg?resize=640%2C426"
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Carousel;
```

In my Carousel.css file:

```
.carousel {
    background-color: red;
    .test {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

When I check the rendered HTML, I can see carousel class and its properties coming in the parent div. But the child img tag shows the class name but no property is associated with it.

Any idea what Im doing wrong here?

**EDIT:: Sam's suggestions worked and Im summarising the changes that solved it:**

Since nesting is a feature of css, we need to use sass or less. And for that I used postcss-loader.

Updated webpack config rules section:

```
rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
                        }
                    },
                    *"postcss-loader"*
                ]
            }
```

Also added a postcss.config.js file like this:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require("postcss-nested")({
            /* ...options */
        })
    ]
};
```

And added postcss-loader, postcss-nested packages using npm install -D option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]How are you importing the css file ?

You can follow the below way to import too,

In your component,

```
import ‘styles.css’
```

In HTML element,

```
<div className='carousel'>
  <div className='test'></div>
</div>
```

In webpack config,

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
}
```

Comment: This is how Im importing:  import styles from "./Carousel.css";

Comment: Try importing it as import from ‘./Carousel.css’ and you can just refer the class..

Comment: Can you please try the webpack config I have updated in my answer ?

Comment: I tried that now. But now both parent and child styles are not getting applied.

Comment: Just noticed that you have declared .test class inside .carousel class, which is not possible in .css file, you will need SASS or LESS to do that, else you can .carousel {
  background-color: red;
}

.carousel > .test {
    width: 600px;
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171818/discussion-between-john-sam-and-phoenix).

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam. That solved it. I used postcss-loader with postcss.config.js (with postcss-nested option inside it) and everything just worked.

Comment: @phoenix can you please share the exact config of postcss?